# MATLAB colorbar ticks change after saving

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I'm changing the ticks and tick-labels of my colorbar .. however, after saving the figure (*.fig) and re-opening the figure, It looks like MATLAB moved the ticks elsewhere . 
has anyone encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of things it could be; First try:

```
set(fig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
```

If that doesn't work, you're going to have to give more information about how exactly you save it (through code or GUI, what command?) and maybe even how you set your ticks n' labels.

Comment: this doesn't work. what i'm doing is this: I am re-opening a *.fig file that I want to fix its colorbar ticks. then:  
1. colorbar('off');
2. c = colorbar;
3. set(c,'YTick',[0 1 2 3 4 5]); 
4. set(c,'YTickLabel,{'0','tick1','tick2','3','4','5'}):
5. save with GUI

Comment: hrm, I don't see anything obvious.  You could try saveas command instead of GUI: saveas(gcf,'test.fig')